# Can I put my css in another place than a styles tag of nuxt 3 component?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

Can I put my css in another place than a styles tag of nuxt 3 component? For example, I'd like to put my css in a separate scss file. Is it possible?

I am new in nuxt 3. I've just been reading the documentation and found there about single-file components as a way of creating components.